# mySQL make a subtraction between 2 row value

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to figure out a simple to make a subtraction between 2 row value..

```
Num_groupe |  num_lot   |   num_secti | ship_date | qte_1 | qte_2 | qte_3 | qte_4
Instock    |    D2312   |   01        | 12-juin   | 10    | 30    | 10    | 10
Instock    |    D2312   |   09        | 12-juin   | 8     | 4     | 6     | 4
Instock    |    C7788   |   01        | 18-sept   | 30    | 10    | 25    | 25
Instock    |    C7788   |   09        | 18-sept   | 5     | 8     | 5     | 8
Instock    |    W3300   |   01        | 11-déc    | 10    | 25    | 30    | 10
Instock    |    W3300   |   09        | 11-déc    | 5     | 4     | 5     | 8
Instock    |    Q1234   |   01        | 03-févr   | 10    | 25    | 10    | 30
Instock    |    Q1234   |   09        | 03-févr   | 6     | 5     | 8     | 5
```

each `num_lot` has a `num_section` 01 and 09, now I want to subtract 'qty value' between each section lot .

Ex.

```
lot D2312 | qte_1 :  10 - 8 = **2** | qte_2 : 30 - 4 = **26**  .....
```

**expected result**:

```
Num_groupe |  num_lot   |   num_secti | ship_date | qte_1 | qte_2 | qte_3 | qte_4
Instock    |    D2312   |   01        | 12-juin   | 2     | 26    | 6     | 6
Instock    |    C7788   |   01        | 18-sept   | 25    | 2     | 20    | 7
```

Any suggestion?  coalesce? sumif?  I'm stuck here :S

Thanks guys,
GC

Answer (score 0):

I think a `SUM IF` would do the task. From the example, I think you want to subtract values where `num_secti` is `9` from those where it is `1`. Try the following query:

```
SELECT
    Num_groupe,
    num_lot,
    ship_date,
    SUM( IF(num_secti = 1, qte_1, -1 * qte_1) ) AS qte_1,
    SUM( IF(num_secti = 1, qte_2, -1 * qte_2) ) AS qte_2,
    SUM( IF(num_secti = 1, qte_3, -1 * qte_3) ) AS qte_3,
    SUM( IF(num_secti = 1, qte_4, -1 * qte_4) ) AS qte_4
FROM <your table name>
GROUP BY num_lot
```

Here is the fiddle from your example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d3095/2